# How to change default color of points in ggplot2 conditional aes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the default colors (currently blue and red) of the points in ggplot2 to another color set.

```
ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color=displ<5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data=mpg) + 
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x=displ, y=hwy, color=displ<5)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("gold", "red"))
```

Here, we use a logical vector, which is converted to numeric to provide a two-color scale i.e. the value for `aes(color)` is `as.integer(mpg$displ < 5)`.

We then convert this into another two-color scale of our choice, here using named values for colors. This gives:

[image]

For more choices for colors, see the following (in `package:grDevices`, so should be loaded by default):

```
demo("colors")
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benefit of the future readers.